# Redirect 404 error to other site

Tags: django, redirect, django-urls

I want to redirect all pages with 404 error to another site example.com. I tried to write something like this:

```
handler404 = 'index.views.custom404'
def custom404(request):    
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

But it doesn't work.
What should I write in urls.py and views.py for this operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write the fully qualified url:

```
handler404 = 'index.views.custom404'
def custom404(request):    
    return HttpResponseRedirect('http://othersite.com/custom404.html')
```

Comment: It was my fault. I wrote `render_to_response`. Now it starts to work. After i set `DEBUG=False` error starts to be 500. Then I add to settings.py `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`. So now all is working. Thank you!